# Automessage on Discord every minute

Tags: javascript, discord

I would like to know how to autosend messages so i can level up in a bot without doing nothing, is there a code or something so it does the command "?work" every 60 seconds (1 minute)?

Comment: You could create your own bot using the provided API https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro. What you aim to create is very easy using this framework.

Comment: I dont know how to use it

Comment: I want a simple code to put in Console